# Overriding the global data argument in R with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am learning some R by going through *[R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/)* book by Grolemund and Wickham. [In chapter 3.6](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html#geometric-objects), they have the following code to demonstrate how to override the global data argument:

```
ggplot(data = mpg, mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(color = class)) + 
  geom_smooth(data = filter(mpg, class == "subcompact"), se = FALSE)
```

This works fine for them supposedly, but when I run this code, I get an error:

```
Error in class == "subcompact" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Answer (score 2):

The authors assume you have the `dplyr` (or `tidyverse`) package loaded.  If you use `dplyr::filter` in place of `filter`, or use `library(dplyr)` or `library(tidyverse)` first, this code will work.

(Longer version: there is a `filter()` function in base R that does something entirely different (see `?stats:filter`).  The `tidyverse` authors decided to re-use that name for a different function (see `?dplyr::filter`).